# How do I repeat sprite horizontally ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I have got the code to repeat X- and Y- which is:

```
 bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ipadbgpattern.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 3000, 3000)];
        bg.position = ccp(500,500);
        ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
        [bg.texture setTexParameters:&params];
        [self addChild:bg];
```

However, I do not know how to change the params in order for the background to repeat along the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no parameter for that. Just make sure the CGRect spans the region where you want the texture to repeat, and the texture itself must be a power of two (ie 1024x1024).

I'm guessing that maybe you're using a 1024x768 texture and then you'll see a gap between texture repeats.

Comment: oh yeah right thanks. I knew about the size of the image (power of 2) but my rect was not the right size. Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved at the GL level, since GL_REPEAT expects textures with power-of-two dimensions.

Take a look at my TiledSprite class for a rather unoptimized, but functional means of arbitrarily repeating an arbitrarily-sized texture or subtexture:

https://gist.github.com/Nolithius/6694990

Here's a brief look at its results and usage:

http://www.nolithius.com/game-development/cocos2d-iphone-repeating-sprite